# Convert Json response from Observable to Array of objects in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

i have an interface

```
export interface Table {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    status: string;
    level: string;
    description: string;
  
}
```

in my service i'm uing HttpClient to make a GET request to get the data from the backend server

```
    public tables: Array<Table>;

    public getTables(): Observable<Table[]> { 
         return this.http.get<Table[]>(this.endpoint + 'get-tables');
    }
```

in my page controller i'm calling this service function, i wan to convert the json data to an Array of objects with the type of the interface 'Table'

```
this.tableService.getTables().subscribe((response: Table[]) => {
            this.tableService.tables = response;
});
```

I'm not getting the response converted into an array of objects in my array 'tables' do you know why is that ?

expecting the Json response to be converted into an array of objects

Comment: Any errors? Can you share the structure of `getTables` response?

Comment: In your service, the type is `Offer[]`, and in your controller you write `Table[]`. Of course it won't work. And you have the `Event` interface for what? Because in your copied code, you don't use it.

Comment: Please check the post now i have edited it thanks for your remarks !

Comment: @wepierrre, show the response of `getTables` api.

Answer (score 0):

First try this to init your Table Array:

```
   public tables!: Table[];

    public getTables(): Observable<Table[]> { 
         return this.http.get<Table[]>(this.endpoint + 'get-tables');
    }
```

This **!** (exclamation mark) is important if you use the strict mode. So a variable declared in a class needs to be initialized. But this only as a side note.

If this not work, so post your response JSON from the server please. But if this looks like this:_

```
[
  {
    id: xxx,
    name: xxx,
  },
  ...
]
```

Then it should work with my code.